# how to load jstree when a button is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

how to load jstree when some button is clicked.

its working fine with document ready but need to load tree is required.

any help would be great

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you meant, but you can just intialize the jsTree inside a jQuery click-event:

```
$("#someButton").click(function() {
   $("#treeContainer").jsTree({
      ... jsTree options
   });
});
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yZQJH/8/